# How to find phase proportion at equilibrium - from iron-carbon diagram - Leblond

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, metallurgy, welding

{Equilibrium proportion P, this is the proportion which is reached at a constant temperature after an infinitely long time:P is also the austenite proportion in the case of extremely slow heating. It is determined by the fact that the free enthalpy of the pearlite-austenite mixture is a minimum at the temperature T for this particular proportion P. It can be read from an iron-carbon diagram (incorporating effects of alloying elements).}

above {Equilibrium ....} read from journal paper.
My question is how to find P from the iron-carbon diagram??
Explain in detail if possible with example.
Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the lever rule or tie line constructions?

Comment: Pearlite and austenite  cannot be in equilibrium together.

Comment: In the paper author also mentioned that effective phase proportion at equilibrium can be calculated by CCT diagram. How?

Comment: In both the IT ( isothermal )  and CCT ( continuous cooling transformation ) diagrams , the phases present depend on the time; so as I understand it -not equilibrium. The phase diagram represents static phases independent of time.